# gitlab + GKE + AutoDevops auto-deploy deploy fail. error: arguments in resource/name form must have a single resource and name. How to find a mistake?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, gitlab-ci

I am new to gitlab CI. So I am trying to use https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Deploy.gitlab-ci.yml, to deploy simple test django app to the kubernetes cluster attached to my gitlab project using a custom chat https://gitlab.com/aidamir/citest/tree/master/chart. All things goes well, but the last moment it show error message from kubectl and it fails. here is output of the pipeline:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.2.0 (a987417a)
  on docker-auto-scale 72989761
Using Docker executor with image registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-deploy-image:v0.1.0 ...
Running on runner-72989761-project-13952749-concurrent-0 via runner-72989761-srm-1568200144-ab3eb4d8...
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/myporject/kubetest/.git/
Created fresh repository.
From https://gitlab.com/myproject/kubetest
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
Checking out 3efeaf21 as master...

Skipping Git submodules setup
Authenticating with credentials from job payload (GitLab Registry)
$ auto-deploy check_kube_domain
$ auto-deploy download_chart
Creating /root/.helm 
Creating /root/.helm/repository 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/cache 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/local 
Creating /root/.helm/plugins 
Creating /root/.helm/starters 
Creating /root/.helm/cache/archive 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml 
Adding stable repo with URL: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com 
Adding local repo with URL: http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts 
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /root/.helm.
Not installing Tiller due to 'client-only' flag having been set
"gitlab" has been added to your repositories
No requirements found in /builds/myproject/kubetest/chart/charts.
No requirements found in chart//charts.
$ auto-deploy ensure_namespace
NAME                           STATUS    AGE
kubetest-13952749-production   Active    46h
$ auto-deploy initialize_tiller
Checking Tiller...
Tiller is listening on localhost:44134
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.0", GitCommit:"05811b84a3f93603dd6c2fcfe57944dfa7ab7fd0", GitTreeState:"clean"}
[debug] SERVER: "localhost:44134"

Kubernetes: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13+", GitVersion:"v1.13.7-gke.24", GitCommit:"2ce02ef1754a457ba464ab87dba9090d90cf0468", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-12T22:05:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.0", GitCommit:"05811b84a3f93603dd6c2fcfe57944dfa7ab7fd0", GitTreeState:"clean"}

$ auto-deploy create_secret
Create secret...
secret "gitlab-registry" deleted
secret/gitlab-registry replaced
$ auto-deploy deploy
secret "production-secret" deleted
secret/production-secret replaced
Deploying new release...
Release "production" has been upgraded.
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Sep 11 11:12:21 2019
NAMESPACE: kubetest-13952749-production
STATUS: DEPLOYED

RESOURCES:
==> v1/Deployment
NAME               READY  UP-TO-DATE  AVAILABLE  AGE
production-djtest  1/1    1           1          46h

==> v1/Job
NAME                        COMPLETIONS  DURATION  AGE
djtest-update-static-auik5  0/1          3s        3s

==> v1/PersistentVolumeClaim
NAME               STATUS  VOLUME  CAPACITY  ACCESS MODES  STORAGECLASS  AGE
nginx-storage-pvc  Bound   nfs     10Gi      RWX           3s

==> v1/Pod(related)
NAME                                READY  STATUS             RESTARTS  AGE
djtest-update-static-auik5-zxd6m    0/1    ContainerCreating  0         3s
production-djtest-5bf5665c4f-n5g78  1/1    Running            0         46h

==> v1/Service
NAME               TYPE       CLUSTER-IP  EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)   AGE
production-djtest  ClusterIP  10.0.0.146  <none>       5000/TCP  46h


NOTES:
1. Get the application URL by running these commands:
  export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace kubetest-13952749-production -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=djtest,app.kubernetes.io/instance=production" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
  echo "Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080 to use your application"
  kubectl port-forward $POD_NAME 8080:80

error: arguments in resource/name form must have a single resource and name
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Please help me to find the reason of the error message.

I did look to the auto-deploy script from the image registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-deploy-image:v0.1.0. There is a settings variable to disable rollout status check

```
  if [[ -z "$ROLLOUT_STATUS_DISABLED" ]]; then
    kubectl rollout status -n "$KUBE_NAMESPACE" -w "$ROLLOUT_RESOURCE_TYPE/$name"
  fi
```

So setting

```
variables: 
   ROLLOUT_STATUS_DISABLED: "true"
```

prevents job fail. But I still have no answer why the script does not work with my custom chat?. When I do execution of the status checking command from my laptop it shows nothing errors.

```
kubectl rollout status -n kubetest-13952749-production -w "deployment/production-djtest"
deployment "production-djtest" successfully rolled out
```

I also found a complaint to a similar issue 
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/4737, but there is no activity on the post.

It is my gitlab-ci.yaml:

```
image: alpine:latest

variables:
  POSTGRES_ENABLED: "false"
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  ROLLOUT_RESOURCE_TYPE: deployment
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""  # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4501

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy  # dummy stage to follow the template guidelines
  - review
  - dast
  - staging
  - canary
  - production
  - incremental rollout 10%
  - incremental rollout 25%
  - incremental rollout 50%
  - incremental rollout 100%
  - performance
  - cleanup

include:
   - template: Jobs/Deploy.gitlab-ci.yml  # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Deploy.gitlab-ci.yml


variables:
   CI_APPLICATION_REPOSITORY: eu.gcr.io/myproject/django-test
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> error: arguments in resource/name form must have a single resource and name

That issue you linked to has `Closed (moved)` in its status because it was moved from [issue 66016](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/66016#note_203406467), which has what I believe is the real answer:

> Please try adding the following to your .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
variables:
  ROLLOUT_RESOURCE_TYPE: deployment
```

Using **just** the `Jobs/Deploy.gitlab-ci.yml` omits [the `variables:` block from `Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/v12.2.5/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml#L55) which correctly sets that variable

In your case, I think you just need to move that `variables:` up to the top, since (afaik) one cannot have two top-level `variables:` blocks. I'm actually genuinely surprised your `.gitlab-ci.yml` passed validation

---

Separately, if you haven't yet seen, you can set the `TRACE` variable to [switch auto-deploy into `set -x` mode](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-deploy-image/blob/v0.2.2/src/bin/auto-deploy#L3) which is super, super helpful in seeing exactly what it is trying to do. I believe your command was trying to run `rollout status /whatever-name` and with just a slash, it doesn't know what kind of name that is.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this error in different context. There shouldn't be spaces when you're passing multiple resource type.

`kubectl get deploy, rs, po -l app=mynginx` # wrong

`kubectl get deploy,rs,po -l app=mynginx` # right